# PHP Require and Include GET

Tags: php, get, require-once

I would like to require a file but also pass GET variables through the url, but when I write:

```
<?php
   require_once("myfile.php?name=savagewood");
?>
```

I get a fatal error. How would I accomplish this functionality in a different way, such that I don't get a fatal error?

Comment: Looking back 11 years at the questions I asked on SO is so embarrassing 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

variables will be available as normal you do not have to pass like this.

```
$name='savagewood';
require_once("myfile.php");
```

`$name` will be available in `myfile.php`

Comment: Of course only if they're in the same scope, or the include script is non-procedural or $name resides within the globals.

Comment: in my case this is not working. `$name = $_POST['test'];` here i got value of $name. but in `myfile.php` not getting value of $name;

Comment: how to used varible globally?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$getVarsArray = $_GET;
$postVarsArray = $_POST;
/* n number of variables and lines of code*/
include('script-a.php');
?>
```

Now in script-a.php has access to `$getVarsArray` and `$postVarsArray` and if in any case you are in doubt you can use `$GLOBALS` to access any variable throughout the life cycle of a script. But using global variables is a sin. :)

Comment: `$_GET` and `$_POST` are *[superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php)*, meaning that they exist in every scope.  Copying the GPC superglobals into another variable like this is *beyond silly* and borderline insane.  Don't do that.

Comment: @Charles, using those GET and POST variables w/out treating them will be equally _beyond silly_ and borderline insane. I never do that. The **sane** will treat those superglobals & will copy them and unset POST/GET vars. Or a paranoid may even write his own implementation for using GET/POST var. This being, not in the scope of the question, wasn't mentioned. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to pass the variables to the new file, because by including the new file the variables are maintained.
Remember that $ _GET is an array, and it can be modified within the script.

```
<?php
   $_GET['name'] = "savagewood";
   require_once("myfile.php");
?>
```

On this case, `$_GET['name']` is accesible from the "*myfile.php*"

Answer (score -2):

I think I have got a perfect solution to your problem. You can use `implode` function of PHP. But I would strongly recommend doing Shakti Singh's code.

**SOLUTION CODE**

```
echo implode(file('http://path-to-your-site/your-dir/myfile.php?name=savagewood'));
```